# how to create multiple Routes component in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to have different dashboards with different users with different links and routes.i try to write code for change route in reactjs but that's not working!

Well I write this code for creating routerbrowser:

```js
export default class App extends Component {

  state={
    usertype:"std",
  }
  showLink(){
    switch(this.state.usertype){
      case "tcr":
      return(
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact>
            <MainPage container={this.state.container}/>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/students">
            <Student container={this.state.container}/>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/payam">
            <MessageT container={this.state.container}/>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      );
      break;
      case "std":
      return(
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact>
            <MainPageD container={this.state.container}/>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/payamha">
            <MessageS container={this.state.container}/>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      )    
      break;    
      default:
      return(
        <div></div>
      ) 
      break;   
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Navbar/>
          <Sidenav usertype={this.state.usertype}/>
          {this.showLink}
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

and this code for sidenav and Links:

```js
export default class Sidenav extends Component {

  sideLink(){
    switch(this.props.usertype){
      case "tcr":
      return (
        <div className="sidebar bg-dark fixed">
          <ul className="text-center ulside">
            <Link to="/" className="aside"> 
              <li className="liside">  home
              </li>
            </Link>  
            <Link to="/searches" className="aside"> 
              <li className="liside">  searches
              </li>
            </Link> 
            <Link to="/payam" className="aside"> 
              <li className="liside">   messages
              </li>
            </Link>   
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
      break;
      case "std":
      return(
        <div className="sidebar bg-dark fixed">
          <ul className="text-center ulside">
            <Link to="/" className="aside"> 
              <li className="liside">home
              </li>
            </Link>   
            <Link to="/students" className="aside"> 
              <li className="liside"> students
              </li>
            </Link> 
            <Link to="/payamha" className="aside"> 
              <li className="liside"> messages
              </li>
            </Link>   
          </ul>
        </div>
      )
      break;  
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div dir="rtl">
        <div>
          <div>
            {this.sideLink}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

i want to create spacial components for each user and use those for Sidenav.
how can i fix this problem??

please help me

thanks.

Comment: "that's not working" -- please be more specific. What's not working? What's the behavior you'd like to see but don't?

Answer (score 0):

just add a userType props to each routes and create a ProtectedRoute component

1 = teacher

2 = student

```
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/"  exact>
        <MainPage container={this.state.container}/>
      </Route>
     
      <ProtectedRoute path="/students" userType={1} layout={teacherSideNav} >
        <Student container={this.state.container}/>
      </ProtectedRoute>
      <ProtectedRoute path="/payam" userType={1} layout={teacherSideNav}  >
        <MessageT container={this.state.container}/>
      </ProtectedRoute>
  
      <Route path="/payamha" userType={2} layout={studentSideNav} >
        <MessageS container={this.state.container}/>
      </Route>
    </Switch>
```

then Apply a logic in the ProtectedRoute component